# Correct MS Access Query / Linq to use

Tags: c#, linq, ms-access

I have this Table

**TBLAttendance**

- EmployeeCode int (Primary Key)
- LogType int (0=am log in, 1 = am log out, 2 = pm log in, 3 = pm log out)
- TimeLog datetime

I want to produce output for each employee in the following format

```
| EmployeeCode | AM_LOG_IN | AM_LOG_OUT | PM_LOG_IN | PM_LOG_OUT |
|--------------|-----------|------------|-----------|------------|
| 12345        | 09:30:01  | 12:02:04   | 13:15:06  | 18:05:02   |
```

I'm using MSAccess, please help me with the right query/approach.
I was able to do this with lots of codes but i dont like my solution. 
Im okay with using LINQ..

Comment: Nobody cares if you are newbie or not. What have you tried so far. And for me, I don't get what you are actually asking.

Comment: Can you please post some of your example SQL code that you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Madhawas's as a starting point:

```
SELECT 
    A.EmployeeCode, 
    Sum(A.AI) AS AM_LOG_IN, 
    Sum(A.AO) AS AM_LOG_OUT, 
    Sum(A.PI) AS PM_LOG_IN, 
    Sum(A.PO) AS PM_LOG_OUT 
FROM
    (SELECT 
        EmployeeCode, 
        TimeLog AS AI, Null AS AO, Null AS PI, Null AS PO  
    FROM TBLAttendance
    WHERE LogType = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        EmployeeCode, 
        Null AS AI, TimeLog AS AO, Null AS PI, Null AS PO  
    FROM TBLAttendance
    WHERE LogType = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        EmployeeCode, 
        Null AS AI, Null AS AO, TimeLog AS PI, Null AS PO  
    FROM TBLAttendance
    WHERE LogType = 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        EmployeeCode, 
        Null AS AI, Null AS AO, Null AS PI, TimeLog AS PO  
    FROM TBLAttendance
    WHERE LogType = 3
    ) AS A
GROUP BY A.EmployeeCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT A.EmployeeCode, A.AM_LOG_IN, A.AM_LOG_OUT, A.PM_LOG_IN, A.PM_LOG_OUT FROM(
SELECT EmployeeCode, TimeLog AS AM_LOG_IN  FROM TBLAttendance
WHERE LogType = 0

UNION

SELECT EmployeeCode, TimeLog AS AM_LOG_OUT  FROM TBLAttendance
WHERE LogType = 1

UNION

SELECT EmployeeCode, TimeLog AS PM_LOG_IN  FROM TBLAttendance
WHERE LogType = 2

UNION

SELECT EmployeeCode, TimeLog AS PM_LOG_OUT  FROM TBLAttendance
WHERE LogType = 3
) A
GROUP BY A.EmployeeCode
```

Comment: Should I  really use UNION rather than JOIN?